# How to iterate if object can be string or array

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

I have an object in a rails model that can either be a string or an array. In my view I have the following:

```
<% current_user.transaction[:account_name].each do |name| %>
```

If the object `account_name` is a string, then it throws an error.

I want to run something like this:

```
<% current_user.transaction[:account_name].each, if sting? each_line do |name| %>
```

using `each_line` if the object is a string, but using `each` if it is an array. I am not sure if this is the best solution. Any ways to make this work regardless of whether the object is an array or string?

Comment: Could you please full block so that I can modify the code

Comment: _"I have an object [...] that can either be a string or an array"_ – **that** is the problem you should fix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the splat operator. eg:

```
str = "hello"
arr = ["hi"]

[*str]
# => ["hello"] 
[*arr]
# => ["hi"]
```

So your code becomes

```
[*current_user.transaction[:account_name]].each do |name|
```

Comment: Cool I didn't know this syntax before

Comment: Note that `*` calls `to_a` under the hood which can have undesired results if your objects implement a custom `to_a`, e.g. `[*Time.now]`

Answer (score 3):

```
<% Array(current_user.transaction[:account_name]).each do |name| %>
   balaballa
<% end %>
```

Note that `Array(element)` would do nothing if you pass in an array, and try to convert the element with array if it is not an array.

If element is nil, then it would simply return you [], and nothing would be looped.

Comment: What if array is null?

Comment: @DineshSaini: `Array(nil) = []`

Comment: @DineshSaini: since Array(nil) give u empty array, it would be `[].each`

Comment: Correct we have to handle for nil in the loop, right? (+1 for you)

Comment: @DineshSaini: nope. if `current_user.transaction[:account_name]` is nil, then an empty array would be returned. (instead of [nil]). Meaning, [].each would never execute.

Answer (score 0):

```
<% if current_user.transaction[:account_name].is_a?(String) %>
  <% current_user.transaction[:account_name].each_line do |name| %>
      balaballa
  <% end %>
<% elsif current_user.transaction[:account_name].is_a?(Array)%>
  <% current_user.transaction[:account_name].each do |name| %>
      balaballa
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You have missed the case if array is null and loop is calle